# Angular: How to save Id in localStorage?

Tags: angular, local-storage

For example on my site I have a Url:

```
http://localhost:4200/help?id=614e163c-62cd-4e05-bf53-20ef340170fe
```

I want to save the id in localStorage and not display it in the url.

My code for this sample:

ts:

```
navigate(nav:string){
    this.router.navigate([`/${nav}`], { queryParams: {id: this.user?.id}})
              .then(() => {
          window.location.reload();
    });
  }
```

html:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a (click)="navigate('help')" class="nav-link">How to play?</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Why `window.location.reload();` after the navigation?

Comment: Because I'm using signalR so it's fixing me bug

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing well.

Not sure about what do you mean by **not display it in the url** but as for the other part i.e. **I want to save the id in localStorage**, I hope the follwing code helps:

```
  constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params : any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id', params['id']);
    });
  }
```

You can see the id in the localStoarge(in Application tab). [image: Screenshot attached]

Edit:

When you combine the above functionality with promise you can achieve the desired output as follows:

```
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
          localStorage.setItem('id', params['id']);
        })
      );
    });

    promise
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/help'], { queryParams: {} });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('insdie error');
      });
```

Note: Add imports as required.

Comment: I was going to save the id in localStorage
And change the url to
**http: // localhost: 4200 / help**

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your comment, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Basend on the snippets you shared, I guess following should work:-

```
navigate(nav:string){
    this.router.navigate([`/${nav}`]).then(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('userId', this.user?.id)
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's not good for me though the url is clean but once I navigate the id site is not saved behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

Use the `skipLocationChange` property could be used to protect a user from seeing URL change. Or use `replaceUrl` to "hide/obfuscate" it from url which user sees. Use `localStorage.setItem()` to set item in localStorage. Though users also have access to localStorage, so it's not completely hidden. If you really want to hide it, store the id in memory (e.g an Angular service) but just so you know, when you do `window.reload()` all services and memory is wiped.

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationBehaviorOptions#skipLocationChange

```js
navigate(nav:string){
    this.router.navigate([`/${nav}`], { queryParams: {id: this.user?.id}, skipLocationChange: true})
              .then(() => {
 localStorage.setItem('id', this.user?.id);
          window.location.reload();
    });
  }
```

Comment: It does not allow me to navigate my site it always brings me back to a specific page and I also wanted the url to be clean and the id to be kept behind the scenes